# How to configure Wildfly/java to use specific ciphers for https

Tags: java, security, https, jce

I am having problems configuring my wildfly-server (8.2.0-Final) to use specific ciphers for my https-configuration.

I am running java 8 (1.8.0_45, with JCE security extensions installed, which does not seem te make a difference).

This is a snippet of my standalone.xml:

```
<https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SslRealm" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA"/>
```

When I test my server using www.ssllabs.com, I only get

```
   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK    128
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS    128
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS    256
```

According to Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation for JDK 8, several of these ciphers (for example, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) are included and enabled by default in java 8.

Does anyone know why the default-enabled ciphers are not showing up and how can I get these ciphers to be added for my server?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Can you try adding this to your https-listeners element:
enabled-protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"